# How to download RAR files with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I try the following code to download a RAR file, fs creates the file but doesn't write anything in it. So basically it downloads an empty file, I've also tried packages from npm but they gave the same result. I do not seem to get any errors.

```
const downloadFile = (url, path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, (response) => {
      const file = createWriteStream(path);
      response.pipe(file);
      file.on("finish", () => {
        file.close();
        resolve();
      });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by using Axios to download it.

```
const downloadFile = (file) => {
  axios({
    method: "get",
    url: file,
    responseType: "stream"
  }).then(function (response) {
    response.data.pipe(createWriteStream("./update.rar"));
  });
}
```